# Where is the left recursion?

Tags: antlr, left-recursion

The below is a snippet of an ANTLR grammar which works fine.

It is intended to become a tex-parser.

If I modify rule `everywhere` by uncommenting `| text`, ANTLR reports a left recursion in rule `escSeq` 
which I think is funny.
I cannot find a left recursion: either I am blind or I misunderstood what left recursion is.

Any suggestions?

```
afterNewline : (everywhere | par );

par : EoL {System.out.println("<PAR>");} afterNewline ;

everywhere : (Esc escSeq //| text
        );

escSeq : (
            EoL          {System.out.println("<cmd:''>");}        afterNewline |
            Space        {System.out.println("<cmd:' '>");}       skipSpace |
            name=Letter+ {System.out.println("<cmd:"+$name.text+">");} skipSpace |
            Other        {System.out.println("<cmd:Other>");}      inLine // **** Other is too restrictive. 
        );

text : (Letter | Other) inLine;

skipSpace : (everywhere | (Space|EoL) {System.out.println("<SKIP>");});

inLine : (everywhere | Space | EolInLine);

EolInLine : EoL {System.out.println("<text:' '>");};

texDocument : afterNewline EOF;
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in grammars but: `everywhere` => `text` => `inLine` => `everywhere`

Comment: Ah, i see from what antlr produced: it requires 
    options {
        backtrack=true ;
    }
which seems to allow recursion at all. 
Then it works fine... at least for small documents, 
because the history of nonterminals is stored on the stack 
which carries the risk of <stackoverflow> 
(good intuition to post it on stackoverflow.com ;-) )

I think, my grammar is conceptually inappropriate, 
at least with antlr.

Answer (score 0):

The grammar above does not have left recursion, with or without the `| text` alternative in `everywhere`. ANTLR 4 does not report left recursion. If ANTLR 3.5 reports left recursion, you should post this as an issue here:

https://github.com/antlr/antlr3/issues